# Strange error when sorting strings with D

Tags: sorting, d, quicksort

I am in the process of learning D (I decided it would be a better beginner friendly language than C++) and I decided to give myself the excercise of implementing a general quicksort in D. My program runs fine when sorting integers but it doesn't compile and throws a strange error when sorting strings.

Here is my code:

```
import std.stdio, std.algorithm;



T[] quickSort(T)(T[] input) {
   if (input.length <= 1) {return input;}
   ulong i = input.length/2;
   auto pivot = input[i];
   input = input.remove(i);
   T[] lesser = [];
   T[] greater = [];
   foreach (x; input) {
      if (x<=pivot)
      {
         lesser ~= x;
      }
      else 
      {
         greater ~=x;
      }
   }
   return (quickSort(lesser) ~ cast(T)pivot ~ quickSort(greater));
}
void main() {
   //Sort integers, this works fine
   //writeln(quickSort([1,4,3,2,5]));
   //Sort string, throws weird error
   writeln(quickSort("oidfaosnuidafpsbufiadsb"));
}
```

When I run it on a string it throws this error:

```
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(7397): Error: template std.algorithm.move does not match any function template declaration. Candidates are:
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(1537):        std.algorithm.move(T)(ref T source, ref T target)
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(1630):        std.algorithm.move(T)(ref T source)
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(1537): Error: template std.algorithm.move cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(dchar, dchar)
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(7405): Error: template std.algorithm.moveAll does not match any function template declaration. Candidates are:
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(1786):        std.algorithm.moveAll(Range1, Range2)(Range1 src, Range2 tgt) if (isInputRange!(Range1) && isInputRange!(Range2) && is(typeof(move(src.front, tgt.front))))
/usr/share/dmd/src/phobos/std/algorithm.d(7405): Error: template std.algorithm.moveAll(Range1, Range2)(Range1 src, Range2 tgt) if (isInputRange!(Range1) && isInputRange!(Range2) && is(typeof(move(src.front, tgt.front)))) cannot deduce template function from argument types !()(string, string)
helloworld.d(9): Error: template instance std.algorithm.remove!(cast(SwapStrategy)2, string, ulong) error instantiating
helloworld.d(31):        instantiated from here: quickSort!(immutable(char))
helloworld.d(31): Error: template instance helloworld.quickSort!(immutable(char)) error instantiating
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that strings are immutable so `remove` won't work (as it manipulates the string)

you can fix that by not removing and not inserting the pivot in the concat:

```
auto pivot = input[i];
//input = input.remove(i); //<- remove this line
T[] lesser = [];
//...
return (quickSort(lesser) ~ quickSort(greater)); //<- remove cast(T)pivot ~
```

or by passing in a dup:

```
writeln(quickSort("oidfaosnuidafpsbufiadsb".dup));
```

Comment: Thanks. Does not removing the pivot make any difference algorithm-wise? Also, what exactly does .dup do? Wouldn't that just make a still immutable version of the string? Why does that fix the mutability problem? Great answer, I just like to learn through asking questions.

Edit: I tried the .dup and it didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: no `dup` makes a mutable copy if you want a immutable copy then use `idup`

Comment: If you havent't already read it, I can recommend Ali Çehreli's online book: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/index.html It will help you get up to speed with D.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put a "d" behind the string to make it utf-32, otherwise remove won't accept it.

```
writeln(quickSort("oidfaosnuidafpsbufiadsb"d.dup));
```